# writeCharacteristic to BLE device that toggles LED on/off

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I got a problem when I try to write two different values to a characteristic. Only the first value I send is written. Im not quite sure how to accomplish this. The value to turn on the LED is 0x07 and the value to turn off the LED is 0x05.

DeviceControlActivity.java:

```
private final ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener servicesListClickListner =
    new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition,
                                    int childPosition, long id) {
            byte[] write_data = new byte[1];
            if (mGattCharacteristics != null) {
                final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic =
                        mGattCharacteristics.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
                final int charaProp = characteristic.getProperties();
                if ((charaProp & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ) > 0) {
                    // If there is an active notification on a characteristic, clear
                    // it first so it doesn't update the data field on the user interface.
                    if (mNotifyCharacteristic != null) {
                        mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(
                                mNotifyCharacteristic, false);
                        mNotifyCharacteristic = null;
                    }
                    mBluetoothLeService.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
                    temp = characteristic.getValue();
                }
                if ((charaProp & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE) > 0) {
                    // If there is an active notification on a characteristic, clear
                    // it first so it doesn't update the data field on the user interface.
                    if (mNotifyCharacteristic != null) {
                        mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(
                                mNotifyCharacteristic, false);
                        mNotifyCharacteristic = null;
                    }
                    if (temp[0] == 0x05)
                    {
                        write_data[0] = 0x07;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        write_data[0] = 0x05;
                    }
                    mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(characteristic, write_data);
                    //characteristic.setValue("testing");
                    //characteristic.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_WRITE);
                }
```

BluetoothLeGatt.java:

```
public boolean writeCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, byte[] data) {
    characteristic.setValue(data);

    boolean status = mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
    return status;
}
```

Comment: Are you getting true for status both times you click ?